# What is the difference between chrono::month and chrono::months

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

What is the difference between the C++20 chrono types/values `month{7}` and `months{7}`?  Isn't it confusing to have two such similar names?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Yes, it can be confusing to have both `month` and `months` when first encountering this library.  However there are consistent naming conventions in this library to help reduce that confusion.  And the benefit is having a clear separation of distinct semantics while retaining short intuitive names.

### `months`

All "predefined" `chrono::duration` types are plural:

- `nanoseconds`
- `microseconds`
- `milliseconds`
- `seconds`
- `minutes`
- `hours`
- `days`
- `weeks`
- `months`
- `years`

So `months` is a [`chrono::duration` type](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.syn):

```
using months = duration<signed integer type of at least 20 bits,
                         ratio_divide<years::period, ratio<12>>>;
```

And it is exactly <sup>1</sup>/<sub>12</sub> of `years`.

```
static_assert(12*months{1} == years{1});
```

You can print it out like this:

```
cout << months{7} << '\n';
```

And the output is:

```
7[2629746]s
```

This reads as 7 units of 2,629,746s.  It turns out that 2,629,746 seconds is the average length of the month in the civil calendar.  Stated differently:

```
static_assert(months{1} == 2'629'746s);
```

(the exact number is not particularly important except for winning bar bets)

### `month`

`month` (singular) on the other hand is *not* a `chrono::duration`.  It is a *calendrical specifier* for a month of the year in the civil calendar.  Or:

```
static_assert(month{7} == July);
```

This can be used to form a date like this:

```
auto independence_day = month{7}/4d/2020y;
```

The algebra of `month` and `months` reflect these different semantics.  For example "July + July" is nonsensical, and thus a compile-time error:

```
auto x = month{7} + month{7};
         ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::chrono::month' and 'std::chrono::month')
```

But this makes perfect sense:

```
auto constexpr x = month{7} + months{7};
static_assert(x == February);
```

And this:

```
auto constexpr x = months{7} + months{7};
static_assert(x == months{14});
```

And yet:

```
auto b = February == months{14};
         ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::chrono::month' and 'std::chrono::months')
```

I.e. `month` and `months` are not only not-equal, they are not even comparable.  They are apples and oranges, if you're into fruit analogies. ;-)

There is a similar relationship between `day` and `days`.  And between `year` and `years`.

---

> If it is plural, it is a `chrono::duration`.

---

And only `<chrono>` has the type safety to help you ensure that these two semantically distinct and yet similar concepts do not get confused with one another in your code.

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be true  `July == July + months(12*x)` regardless  of x? Even for x being INT_MAX?

Comment: Almost.  If `12*x` overflows you've got undefined behavior right there (before `months` constructor runs).  However if the value of `months` is a multiple of 12 (positive or negative), then yes the addition (or subtraction) is essentially a no-op.  You would get the same thing as `July == July + years(x)`.

Comment: You asked your question 17:58 and you answer it at 17:58 too?

Comment: It's not only ok to answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ , https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer