# How do I add a number of days to a date in C++20 chrono?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

Given the new `<chrono>` facilities in C++20, how do I add some number of days (say `n`) to a date?

When I try this I get a compile-time error:

```
auto d = July/4/2020;
auto d2 = d + days{5};
          ~ ^ ~~~~~~~
error: invalid operands to binary expression
   ('std::chrono::year_month_day' and 'std::chrono::days')
```

Comment: Ok, this was the first I'd heard of `chrono::operator/`. Wow. I guess C++ didn't have enough embedded languages already...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A "date" in `<chrono>` is just a time point with days-precision.  And a
"date-time" is just a `chrono::time_point` (usually based on
`system_clock`) with precision finer than `days`.  And the canonical "date type" in
`<chrono>` is:

```
chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock, chrono::days>
```

This is nothing but a `days`-precision `time_point` based on
`system_clock`.  This particular `time_point` also has a convenience
type alias: `sys_days`.

```
using sys_days = time_point<system_clock, days>;
```

So to add a number of days to `sys_days` one just does:

```
sys_days tp = ...;
tp += days{n};
// or
auto tp2 = tp + days{n};
```

If it is just one day, you can also just:

```
++tp;
```

This is very efficient because under the hood it is just adding two
`int`s.

If your `time_point` has precision finer than `days`, it is still the
same procedure to add `days` to it:

```
auto tp = system_clock::now() + days{n};
```

> When I try this I get a compile-time error:

> ```
> auto d = July/4/2020;
> auto d2 = d + days{5};
>           ~ ^ ~~~~~~~
> error: invalid operands to binary expression
>    ('std::chrono::year_month_day' and 'std::chrono::days')
> ```

The variable `d` above has type `year_month_day`.  Even though `year_month_day` is semantically equivalent to `sys_days`,
it does not *directly* support `days`-precision arithmetic.
`year_month_day` is a days-precision time point (but not a
`chrono::time_point`). Instead it is a `{year, month, day}` data
structure. You can easily perform days-precision arithmetic by
converting it to `sys_days` first:

```
auto d = July/4/2020;
auto d2 = sys_days{d} + days{5};
```

In this case, the type of the result `d2` is `sys_days`.  If you would like the
result to have `year_month_day`, then just convert it back:

```
year_month_day d2 = sys_days{d} + days{5};
```

Rationale for this design:

Efficiency.  The conversion from `year_month_day` to `sys_days` (and
back) takes a bit of number crunching.  It isn't a huge amount.  But
it is large compared to a single integral addition.

If the `<chrono>` library provided `days`-precision arithmetic for `year_month_day`,
the algorithm would be to convert the `year_month_day` to `sys_days`,
do the arithmetic, and then convert the result back to
`year_month_day`.  If you have a lot of `days`-precision arithmetic to
do, it is better to just traffic in `sys_days`, and convert to
`year_month_day` only when necessary (i.e. when you need to get the
`year`, `month` or `day` fields out of it).

If the library provided the day-precision arithmetic for `year_month_day`,
clients would blindly use it, not realizing that `year_month_day` is the
wrong data structure for their application.  It would be akin to giving
`std::list` an indexing operator (which would be quite easy to do):

```
template <class T, class A>
T&
list<T, A>::operator[](size_type i)
{
    return *advance(begin(), i);
}
```

Providing such an API just makes it too easy to write inefficient
code. `sys_days` is the data structure of choice for doing `days`
precision arithmetic.

> It still doesn't work for me:
>
> ```
> auto d = July/4/2020;
> auto d2 = sys_days{d} + day{5};
>           ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~
> error: invalid operands to binary expression
>    ('std::chrono::sys_days' and 'std::chrono::day')
> ```

You need to use `days`, not `day`.  `day` is a *calendrical specifier*
for the day of a month in the civil calendar.  `days` is a
`chrono::duration`.  See this [stack overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62249520/576911) for a more in-depth
discussion about the distinction between these two concepts.

> If I have a `year_month_day` and I want to add a few days to it that
> I know won't reach the end of the month, can I do that without
> converting to `sys_days` and thus gain efficiency?

Yes.

```
auto d = July/4/2020;
auto d2 = d.year()/d.month()/(d.day() + days{5});
```

The above simply adds 5 to the `day` field of `d`.  There is no
checking to see if the result goes past the last day of the month.  If
it does go past the last day of the month, that result will be stored
in the day field (up to day 255), and `d2.ok()` will return `false`.

---

`year_month_day` is good for retrieving the `year`, `month` or `day`
fields from a date.  It is also good for `years` and `months`
precision *calendrical* arithmetic. `sys_days` is good for `days`
precision arithmetic, and for converting to a finer precision
(a date-time).

`year_month_day` and `sys_days` can convert to one another with no
information loss.  Use whichever data structure makes the most sense.
And if you forget, the compiler will remind you, just like it does for
`vector` (no `push_front`), `list` (no indexing operator), and
`forward_list` (no `size`).