# Why is it not possible to add a `std::chrono::hours` to a `std::chrono::sys_days`

Tags: c++, literals, duration, c++-chrono

Taking the first steps with `<chrono>` library,
I'm starting with basic arithmetic on a days grained `time_point`.
Thanks to a very useful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734975/7143595) by @HowardHinnant,
I managed to write [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MrG74xfcc):

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    std::chrono::sys_days d {std::chrono::January/31/2022};
    d += std::chrono::days{2}; // ok
    //d += 48h; // error: no match for 'operator+=' with std::chrono::hours
}
```

What is not clear to me is why `d += 48h;` isn't allowed.
The `std::chrono::time_point<>::operator+=` takes a `duration`,
and the *rvalue* in that expression is a `std::chrono::hours` that
in my mind represents a time duration.
What's the philosophy here? Are there different duration types
according to the measure unit that must be compatible with the
granularity of the `time_point`? Why?

On the other hand, I understand why `d += 2d;` gives an error,
since in this case `std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""d`
is a `std::chrono::day`, which is not a duration (that's handy
to form a date literal, although it seems a little inconsistent
to me).
I wonder if there's a more convenient way to express
a duration literal equivalent to `std::chrono::days{2}`.

Comment: Because resolution of `sys_days` is days and not hours, everything beyond that is lost. If you want hour granularity then use hours, or better yet, simply [std::chrono::time_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)

Comment: @Sahsahae In my ingenuity I assumed that `48h` was a duration equivalent to two days, because I couldn't express it with `2d`. I chose a day granularity just to see how it worked, but it seems I have to study better the rationale behind this library.

Comment: *A more convenient way to express a duration literal equivalent to `days{2}`* — nobody can stop you from creating your own `operator""_days`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep That's a good point that I was missing.

Comment: For the basics of durations, time_points and clocks, here's a 1h video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  For a video on how calendars and timezones are built on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adSAN282YIw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add hours to days. What you can't do is implicitly convert that into days again. [You need a cast](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11bf03cb089e2405)

```
d = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::days>(d + 48h);
```

Comment: So the `operator+` accepts `hours`, and the result is a `time_point` in hours. I thought that `d+=48h;` was expressing a clear intent, but I see now that an implicit cast could hide a nasty unwanted behaviour.

Comment: @MatG In this case you'd be dropping a `0`, but in general it's a lossy conversion