Add 1 day to a `year_month_day` std::chrono object?
Using C++20, given (year, month, day) as integers, I want to find the next day, also as (year, month, day). There is a data type in std::chrono, year_month_day, that seems appropriate. But I cannot find any way to add 1 day to a year_month_day object.
I know this can be done with timepoints rather than year_month_day, or even using just the C runtime library, but I am wondering whether there is any way to do so using just year_month_day.

Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62734974/576911

In C++20, the std::chrono library does not allow direct arithmetic operations (like adding days) on std::chrono::year_month_day. However, you can achieve this by combining std::chrono::year_month_day with std::chrono::sys_days, which is a std::chrono::time_point specialization that represents a day in the Gregorian calendar. Here's how you can do it:
Convert your std::chrono::year_month_day to std::chrono::sys_days.
Add one day to the sys_days object.
Convert the resulting sys_days back to std::chrono::year_month_day.
