# How to add chrono::year_month_day to chrono::sys_seconds

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Am holding duration's in a year_month_day.  Is there a simple way to add the year_month_day duration to a time_point like sys_seconds?

```
sys_seconds date1 = {};
sys_seconds dat2 = {};
year_month_day calDuration;
date1 = date2 + calDuration;    //error: no match for ‘operator+’
```

Comment: I don't think that `year_month_day` is a duration. It is a point in time, isn't it? `sys_seconds` is a `time_point`. It just doesn't make sense to add two time points. Rethink your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is chrono catching logic bugs for you at compile-time.  Adding `date2 + calDuration` is akin to adding tomorrow + today.  It just doesn't make sense.  And that's why it is a compile-time error.

What you may mean is that you have durations `years`, `months` and `days`.  This is not the same as the similarly named types `year`, `month` and `day`.  The plural forms are `chrono::duration`s, just like `minutes` and `nanoseconds`.  `days` is `24h`.  And `years` and `months` are the *average* length of those units in the civil calendar.

Conversely, the singular forms `year`, `month` and `day` are the calendrical components that give a name to a day in the civil calendar, e.g. `2020y`, `December`, and `18d`.  And it is these singular forms that make up a `year_month_day`, e.g. `2020y/December/18d`.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62249521/576911) for a deep-dive on the difference between `month` and `months`.

There are multiple ways to add the units `years` and `months` to a `time_point`.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018120/576911) for a deep-dive on that topic.

Comment: Ah - ok - your right I didn't notice that we have both std::chrono::month and std::chrono::months etc. as completely different things.  Guess I'll define a years_months_days then to hold my calendar duration's.

Comment: Sounds good.  And in that case, I'm guessing what you want to do is calendrical arithmetic, as opposed to chronological arithmetic for the `years` and `months` units.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018120/576911 for more details about this distinction and how to handle it.