# Sending (epoch) time from C++ to Javascript

Tags: c++, export, c++20, epoch

Let's say I have the following program to export an object to JSON:

```cpp
struct MyChronoObject {
  std::string name;
  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point birthday;

  MyChronoObject(const std::string name_) : name(name_) {
    birthday = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  }

  std::string toJSON1() {
    std::string s = "{ \"name\": \"" + name + "\", \"birthday\": ";
    s += std::to_string((birthday.time_since_epoch().count() / 1000000));
    s += " }";
    return s;
  }

  std::string toJSON2() {
    std::string s = "{ \"name\": \"" + name + "\", \"birthday\": ";
    s += std::to_string((birthday.time_since_epoch().count()));
    s += " }";
    return s;
  }

  void setBirthday(int birthday_in_seconds) {
    // how do I properly cast this?
  }
};
```

Which, for `toJSON1()`, has the output `{ "name": "Steve", "birthday": 16687719115 }`

There are several problems with this code (which I will mention but will probably address them in separate threads), but first and foremost...

- The number `16687747280` is not correct. It should be one digit shorter for `seconds` or 2 digits longer for `milliseconds` if I go by this: [EpochConverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)
- Not dividing the the birthday by one million, `toJSON2()`, leads to a number that is one digit too long for `microseconds` and 2 digits too short for `nanoseconds`: `16687747280849928`.

So which way would be correct (and most efficient) to store and convert the stored epoch time so that I can export it to something that can be used by Javascript?

Thank you in advance!

---

P.S.: Other questions that I have are:

- How do I cast back a number that the `C++` program receives from the frontend (like in `setBirthday`)?
- Should I even store the date as `chrono` object if seconds are sufficient?
- How do I add exactly one year so that I land on the same date (e.g. 25.1.20**19** to 25.1.20**20**), considering things like leap years, etc.).
- What about dates before 1970?

Answer (score 6):

Note the default unit of `std::chrono::system_clock` is undefined. Instead of using `birthday.time_since_epoch().count() / 1000000`, you should cast the time unit to the appropriate unit for you:

```cpp
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(birthday.time_since_epoch())
    .count()
```

This will give you the amount of second.

You might also use `std::chrono::ceil<seconds>`, `std::chrono::floor<seconds>`, `std::chrono::round<seconds>` for different rounding modes.

---

- To cast from integer back to a `time_point`, you can do:

```cpp
std::chrono::sys_time{std::chrono::seconds{birthday_in_second}};
```

or:

```cpp
std::chrono::sys_time{std::chrono::milliseconds{birthday_in_millisecond}};
```

---

- To add/subtract years, you can use:

```cpp
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto today = std::chrono::year_month_day{std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now)};
auto today_10_years_ago = today - std::chrono::years{10};
```

<del>And you can also use `using namespace std::chrono::literals` to write `10y` instead of `years{10}`.</del> <sub>*This is incorrect, see more information in the comment</sub>

Note `today` and `today_10_years_ago` are `year_month_day` object now. If you want a `time_point` with h/m/s information as well, you can do:

```cpp
auto today_as_time_point = std::chrono::sys_days{today_10_years_ago};

auto time_only = today - now;
auto today_with_time_info = today_as_time_point + time_only;
```

---

- Yes, the `<chrono>` library works with time before epoch.

By requirement, all predefined duration types up to `chrono::hours` are guaranteed to work in the range for at least ±292 years(in practice, many of them will still work in much larger ranges). And types greater than hour, ie. `chrono::days`, `chrono::years` are guaranteed for ±40000 years.

So if you know you are going to do something like `now - years{1000}`, it would be a good idea to convert `now` to a larger unit first.

---

> I'm still a bit overwhelmed by the casting...

Part of the goal of the `<chrono>` library is to give high level access to time/date data while avoiding possible errors.

If you want to cast a more precise duration to a less precise duration, ie. from millisecond to second, you are forced to use an explicit cast or through roundings, which will avoid unintended truncation errors.

For more, you might search for Howard Hinnant's talk on the library.

---

> ... and extracting something like `year` out of it

Depends on your need, if your full goal was to serialize a date information, you might want to utilize `std::format` or [{fmt} library](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) to do it automatically:

```cpp
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::cout << std::format("{:%Y}", now);       // This will print only the year
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MhTvcb6PG) further utilizing formatting libraries. <sub>*Note `{fmt}` library is used as gcc haven't implemented the full `std::format` library.</sub>

Comment: Good answer.  But `10y` is `year{10}`, not `years{10}`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62249520/576911 for an analogous discussion for `month` and `months`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Aww, thank you! Removed the `10y` parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I have to admit I'm still a bit overwhelmed by the casting (and extracting something like `year` out of it). However, the line `std::chrono::sys_time{std::chrono::seconds{birthday_in_second}};` did not work for me. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: `sys_time` is a C++20 name.  If you're in C++11/14/17, you can use this much more verbose name (which `sys_time` is a type alias for):  `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds>`.

Comment: @Markstar Note some of the features are added only in C++20, and not all compilers have implemented all feature. You might check Howard Hinnant(author of `<chrono>` library)'s [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) for more information

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio and have set it to `/std:c++20`. Hmm, I'm also getting an error for `auto today = std::chrono::year_month_day{std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>{now}};` ("no instance of constructor ... matches the argument list").

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xxaKKff4r

Comment: @Markstar Updated the answer, it should be `year_month_day{std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now)}`

Comment: @Markstar *'extracting something like `year` out of it'* -- `std::format` or [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) will be great friend for you.

Answer (score 2):

`duration.count()` returns a number of ticks. Not seconds, nor microseconds, nor nanoseconds. Unless the tick period happens to be 1, 10⁻⁶, or 10⁻⁹ seconds.

You have to multiply that by the period, which is given in class attributes of your duration. Which in you case, depends on the clock type (all those are templates, and the period depend on the actual class)

One way is to cast the duration into a duration whose you know the period.

Like

```cpp
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(birthday.time_since_epoch()).count()
// Instead of birthday.time_since_epoch().count()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the fix. Is this also how you would implement this or is there a better/more efficient way?

Comment: Honestly, I am not a c++ coder (this is probably the first time I answer a `c++` tagged question. I just happen to have already encounter theses types). In my world, that is a very convoluted way to get epoch time in integer. But I also know that in C++, many code seem to be overly convoluted, but in reality are static code, and generates only a few operation in the generated code. So, honestly, I don't know. Maybe all this just means "divide by 100000", in which case, you can't do better.