# How to get std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds> from variables of year,month,day,hour,minute and seconds?

Tags: c++, time, c++20, c++-chrono

I have declared a time_point variable and try to assign values from year month day etc. But it fails when I use sys_days. The code is something as follows.

```
int year=2023;
int month=1;
int day=1;
int hour=1;
int minute=1;
double second=0.000005;
std::chrono::time_point\<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds\> tp;
tp=sys_days{years{year}+months{month}+days{day}}+hour+minute+second;
```

The code encountered errors, but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for helps.

Comment: There are 2 `\\` in your code. Are they meant to be there, or are they copy-paste errors?

Comment: I imagine that the backslashes are escaping the angle brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `double second = 0.000005;`

This line brings questions.  Your title says that you want a `time_point` that holds integral seconds, but here you say you want a precision of `microseconds`, possibly held with `double` representation.  These can't all be true.

Assumption:  You will be fine with a `time_point` holding an integral number of `microseconds`.  To do this, change this line to:

```
int us = 5;  // 5 microseconds
```

---

Your use of some names that are in `std::chrono`, but without the *std::chrono::* prefix, combined with variable names of the same spelling, leads to conflicts.

Assumption:  declare `using namespace std::chrono` and rename your `int` variables to avoid name conflicts:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
int y=2023;
int m=1;
int d=1;
int h=1;
int M=1;
int us = 5;
```

---

Your `time_point` type now must have a different type than that stated in your title:

```
time_point<system_clock, microseconds> tp;
```

This type has a type alias in C++20 that is slightly simpler:

```
sys_time<microseconds> tp;
```

---

The types `years`, `months`, and `days` are all plural, and all `std::chrono::duration` types.  For specifying pieces of the civil calendar, you need the singular spelling of these names:  `year`, `month`, and `day`.  These are calendrical specifiers for the civil calendar.

See [What is the difference between chrono::month and chrono::months](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62249520/576911) for more details on the difference between the singular and plural forms.

The expression `year(y)/month(m)/day(d)` creates a `year_month_day`.  One can convert this to `sys_days` which creates a day-precision `time_point`:

```
sys_days{year{y}/month(m)/day(d)}
```

To this you can add any `duration` type, but not `int`s:

```
tp=sys_days{year{y}/month(m)/day(d)}+hours{h}+minutes{M}+microseconds{us};
```

Unless you need to "pre declare" `tp`, the use of `auto` can simplify things greatly:

```
auto tp = sys_days{year{y}/month(m)/day(d)}
          + hours{h} + minutes{M} + microseconds{us};
```